# Google sheets numbered list

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for a way (formula) to implement google docs functionality called numbered list in google sheets

---

**Example:**

[image: Google docs numbered list]

---

**I want:**

[image: Google sheets (typed manually)]

Comment: based on what criteria?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @player0,
I want to be able to drag the cells and get the number according to the cell above
for example, if the cell A1 is 2.1.1, then A2 should be 2.1.2
A more complex version could be to check another cell to which hierarchy it belongs
for example:
if in cell A1=1 and cell B1="first" and cell B2="second" then B1 should be equal to 1.1

Comment: @Rubén, I have not found this functionality in Google Sheets nor on the Internet, there is no easy way to do it, so I wonder if anyone can think of a formula that simulates this

Comment: Have you already think on that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35711081/1595451

Answer (score 0):

FORMULA TO INCREMENT A1:

```
=left(A1,len(A1)-FIND(".",ArrayFormula(concatenate(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))+1,1)))))&"."&(RIGHT(A1,FIND(".",ArrayFormula(concatenate(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))+1,1))))-1)+1)
```

EXPLANATION:

```
=ArrayFormula(concatenate(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))+1,1)))
```

Return the reverse of A1. e.g. if A1 is 2.1.32, the reverse will be 23.1.2

```
=FIND(".",ArrayFormula(concatenate(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))+1,1))))
```

Find the number of characters to the last "." of the string in A1

```
=RIGHT(A1,FIND(".",ArrayFormula(concatenate(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))+1,1))))-1)+1
```

Retrieves the rightmost integer in A1 and increments it by 1 (i.e. if A1 is "2.1.32" this formula returns 33)

```
=left(A1,len(A1)-FIND(".",ArrayFormula(concatenate(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))+1,1)))))&"."&(RIGHT(A1,FIND(".",ArrayFormula(concatenate(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))+1,1))))-1)+1)
```

Takes the left part of A1, excluding the last integer, and concatenates the incremented rightmost integer

GOOGLE SHEET THAT IMPLEMENTS THIS:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QSAhyzJxdcq47VxpUb-x-YMHqw8yzeZh3ZzRgGCEUIM/edit?usp=sharing